# Configure LG-UM65P Speaker in Windows 10

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors

Attempts to configure Windows 10 to drive the speaker in an [LG-UM65-P monitor](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-29UM65-P-ultrawide-monitor) via DISPLAYPORT have not been successful. Video displays properly on target monitor.  Sound port, from the dock, works as expected

In the past Sound Playback options included the monitor, however, this is not the case now.  The monitors in the device-manager does not reflect that the PC is driving the video of the target monitor.  Is there a process that can prompt the OS to restore the sound monitor's speaker as a playback option?

[image]

Comment: How are you outputting audio to the monitor's speakers? HDMI? Do you have "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconnected Devices" ticked/enabled?

Comment: You didn't forget to plug it in did you? Just checking.

Comment: Good questions.  More details added to address questions

Answer (score 0):

Hows the cable between computer and the monitor, it requires HDMI for to be any use? Have you tried to plug a headphones to the audio-out port of the monitor, it might help with the issue too.

Also try re-connecting the cable while you have both computer and monitor on.